# Create Array from XML nodelist directly without looping through nodelist?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I'm using XML together with VBA and I'm wondering, is there a way to directly create an array from a nodelist without looping over the nodelist and adding all the elements? This would improve speed dramatically I suppose.

Comment: Would help to show your existing code, but I don't think there's a built-in "toArray()" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xml file/data are of table type you could use `ADODB.Recordset` which could be created from xml file. Next you could use `.GetRows method` to create array from retrieved values. Follow the code below and comments inside:

*(Tried and tested for simple access database/table)*

Table in Access:
[image]

```
Sub ArrarFromXML()

    'this code works for Access where test table tblTable was created
    'required references to ActiveX library

    '1. EXPORT
    'create xml file by exporting table

    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    RS.Open "tblTable", CurrentProject.Connection

    RS.Save "xmlFile.xml", adPersistXML

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing

    '2. IMPORT
    'open file and save data in Recordset...

    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    RS.Open "xmlFile.xml", "Provider=MSPersist;", adOpenForwardOnly, _
                        adLockReadOnly, adCmdFile

    '3. ...export Recordset to Array
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = RS.GetRows

    Debug.Print myArray(0, 0)

End Sub
```

Locals window with array values:
[image]

Comment: hmm, well I'm running the XML file directly in an XMLDocument object. The wait is not that long but I wouldn't be able to directly use ADO without saving the xml files first right in this case?